# Get PHP assoc array key in loop

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) 
    {
        for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++)
        {
            (DO THING HERE)
            $row[$i] = str_replace("\n", " ", $row[$i]);
            $row[$i] = str_replace("\r", " ", $row[$i]);
        }

    }
```

I basically want to do, if the associative array key is equal to "email" (so $row['email']) then append "@gmail.com" to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the `MYSQL_NUM` you have there? [That is going to return your data using the column indexes as keys (ie 0, 1, 2, etc)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

You must either

a) find out which column index the `email` field is and do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) 
{
    // 'email' is in column number 5
    $row[5] .='@gmail.com';

    for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++)
    {
        $row[$i] = str_replace("\n", " ", $row[$i]);
        $row[$i] = str_replace("\r", " ", $row[$i]);
    }
}
```

b) OR you can change `MYSQL_NUM` to `MYSQL_ASSOC`, and do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    $row['email'] .='@gmail.com';

    foreach($row as &$value)
    {
        $value = str_replace("\n", " ", $value);
        $value = str_replace("\r", " ", $value);
    }
}
```

Note the `"&"` before `$value` to make it a reference.

I would do the latter (I prefer `foreach` to `for` :)

Comment: way to completely bite my answer bro.  i demand half your rep

Comment: @theman: this SO "heartbeat" implementation is buggy. I didn't even see your answer while I was writing mine.

Comment: crescentfresh, i saw your first comment to mine, its all good, you wrote your response better, i was joking the whole time

Answer (score 5):

Use a foreach loop and get both the key and the value for the assoc array.

```
foreach($row as $key => &$value)
{
    if($key == 'email') $value .= "@gmail.com";
}
```

Also you should be using `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` if you want an associative array returned.

A more efficient way to append to the email key would be something like:

```
if(isset($row['email']))
    $row['email'] .= '@gmail.com';
```

Instead of looping through all the columns.

Comment: not only is this inefficient, its also wrong.  He passed the MYSQL_NUM constant to it, so there are no associative keys.  thanks

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() also fetches associative arrays

Comment: wouldn't you need to get $value by reference if you are going to change it ? i.e. foreach ($row as $key => & $value)

Comment: Adam, you can't change $value inside the loop like that - as foreach operates on a copy of the real array. You would have to do $row[$key] .= '@gmail.com'. Cheers

Comment: adam peck, i see you edited your answer after realizing how wrong you were.  is that a submission of defeat?  I am ready for you to apoligize

Comment: @theman When I originally answered the question I will admit I did not notice the MYSQL_NUM constant. I don't see why that is such a big issue to you.

Comment: cause you downvoted my more-correct answer and then posted a rude comment

Comment: Yes i also see i forgot to get a reference.  it has been corrected.

Comment: @theman: why do you take issue with editing a question to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Paulo had it almost exactly right:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($row as $key => &$value) {
        if($key == 'email') $value .= '@gmail.com';
        $value = str_replace("\n", " ", $value);
        $value = str_replace("\r", " ", $value);
    }
}
```

Note the "&" in the `foreach` line. That means you're modifying the value in the `$row` array, not just a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want but:

```
$row['email'].='@gmail.com';
```

This will append @gmail.com to the email row.